# Docker Cannot Start the image

Tags: docker

```
Have written Dockerfile:
# Webserver container with Edureka Case Study App
# Using Ubuntu base image and Apache Web server
# Version 1

# Pull the Ubuntu image from the local registry
FROM centos


MAINTAINER Viswanath Rajashekar

# Update image
RUN yum install httpd -y

# Add application files
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
ADD ./case-study-app ./

# Start the service
CMD [?/usr/sbin/httpd?,?-D?,?FOREGROUND?]

# Expose application on port 80
EXPOSE 80
```

After building the image and running it using command:
docker run -itd -p 8888:80 case-study-app

Container exits:
root@dockerdca:~/dockerContent# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
2d8b60bce9ed case-study-app '/bin/sh -c [?/usr/s?' 3 seconds ago Exited (127) 2 seconds ago
stoic_swartz

Why?

I need help in setting up the volume in this Dockerfile, PLease help.

Comment: Which part exactly causes the startup failure? Is that a [mcve] already? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `CMD [?/usr/sbin/httpd?,?-D?,?FOREGROUND?]` with `CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: The quotes are important.  I'd generally leave this as `CMD` and not `ENTRYPOINT`; that change (probably) isn't relevant to this problem, and there's no particular requirement to have an `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: thanks man i was new in docker when i posted such a silly question XD thanks for ur help